# Is there any way to detect fullscreen events in youtube iframe api?

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I wish to know when the video is in fullscreen, something like

```
ytvideo.addEventListener('fullscreenChange', e => {
    document.fullscreenElement = e.isFullscreen ? ytvideo.f : null
})
```

I want to mock the FullscreenAPI on iOS devices (currently mocking successfully HTML5 Video and Vimeo SDK)

Answer (score 3):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenchange_event)

```
function callback() {
  if (document.fullscreenElement) {
    console.log('Entering Fullscreen');
  } else {
    console.log('Exiting Fullscreen');
  }
}

document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', callback);
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', callback);
```

Comment: fullscreen is deprecated better to use fullscreenElement